# How to set a Connection's synapse type in the NEST simulator?

Tags: python, nest-simulator

Following the tutorial for the Python interface to the NEST simulator I have created 2 neuron populations and connected them:

```py
import nest
ndict = {"I_e": 200.0, "tau_m": 20.0}
nest.SetDefaults("iaf_psc_alpha", ndict)
neuronpop1 = nest.Create("iaf_psc_alpha", 100)
neuronpop2 = nest.Create("iaf_psc_alpha", 100)

nest.Connect(neuronpop1, neuronpop2, syn_spec={"weight":20.0})
```

But how could I connect them with a specific synapse model like the ones listed in the [model directory](https://nest-simulator.readthedocs.io/en/nest-2.20.1/models/index.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to connect neurons with specific connectivity patterns.

The default connection pattern of `nest.Connect` is "all_to_all".

More details about the available patterns are detailed in the [`Connect` documentation](https://nest-simulator.readthedocs.io/en/nest-2.20.1/ref_material/pynest_apis.html#nest.lib.hl_api_connections.Connect).

You can also see the available rules by calling `nest.ConnectionRules()`.

If you're using ipython or jupyter, you can get the docstring locally by typing `nest.Connect?`.

**EDIT:** to change synapse type (how it transmits incoming signals), please see the ["synapse types" documentation](https://nest-simulator.readthedocs.io/en/nest-2.20.1/guides/connection_management.html#synapse-types).

You can find examples for [tsodyks](https://nest-simulator.readthedocs.io/en/nest-2.20.1/auto_examples/evaluate_tsodyks2_synapse.html) or [quantal_stdp](https://nest-simulator.readthedocs.io/en/nest-2.20.1/auto_examples/evaluate_quantal_stp_synapse.html) synapses.

An example with your populations would be:

```py
# connect populations with depressing synapses
dep_params = {"U": 0.67, "u": 0.67, 'x': 1.0, "tau_rec": 450.0,
              "tau_fac": 0.0, "weight": 250.}

nest.CopyModel("tsodyks_synapse", "dep_syn", syn_param)

nest.Connect(neuronpop1, neuronpop2, syn_spec="dep_syn")
```

for synapses where close subsequent spikes would have less and less effect on the post-synaptic neuron.

Comment: No I'd like to know how to select by which synapse the neurons are being connected to eachother. For example how could I connect `neuronpop1` to `neuronpop2` through the `Tsodyks2Connection` listed in the Model Directory? Or am I conceptually misunderstanding something?

Comment: Oh ok, so from review of the `Connect` documentation I see that it is the "synapse type" that I want to set, I incorrectly called that a "connection model" I'll update my question. Could you give an example in your answer that uses something else than the default `static_synapse` and sets some of its attributes?

Comment: updated the answer with an example using a dynamic tsodyks synapse